# foobar2000 Remove currently playing song from queue hotkey not working

Tags: foobar2000

Hotkey for Removing from playback queue currently playing song is not working.

 Can I set it somehow? Tried global/local hotkey, different keys. All other options work.

Comment: I just tested this shortcut and it's working. I'm using foobar 1.3.3. Have you tried it with a new installation (in portable mode) and without running any other programs in the background?

Comment: I am using 1.3.3 and all other shortcuts are working except this one. I will try to install latest version and let you know. Must close everything first.

Comment: Still nothing...

Comment: What hotkeys have you tried to assign for removing from playback queue?

Are you running any other multimedia programmable software like winamp, hotkey assign software, or any Windows shortcuts that have that key combo already assigned?

Comment: I tried several combos. Shift+numpad numbers, only numpad, ctrl+shift+q, etc., nothing seems to work. Other hotkeyed functions work, like open folder of currently playing song. I don't use any hotkey software.

Comment: Does [this link](http://www.thefreewindows.com/3168/remove-the-currently-playing-track-from-the-playback-queue-playlist-of-foobar2000/) pertain to the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Remove the currently playing track from the default playback queue / playlist of Foobar2000](http://www.thefreewindows.com/3168/remove-the-currently-playing-track-from-the-playback-queue-playlist-of-foobar2000/) :

> Foobar2000 provides a “Remove” command on several occasions, yet not
>   all of them will remove a song from the default playlist when you are
>   listening to it. After experimenting a while I found that the “Remove”
>   command which works is to be found in the “Edit” section.
>
> If you want to remove a track from your playlist (not physically
>   delete it from the disk) using a keyboard shortcut, go to Foobar’s
>   preferences -> Keyboard Shortcuts, press the “Add New” button and use
>   the “filter list” option to find the command “Edit / Selection /
>   Remove”.
>
> Assign a keyboard shortcut to this command (make it global to have it
>   available even if you work with other applications) and enjoy easy
>   creation of playlists.
>
> Note that Foobar won’t start playing the next track automatically
>   after you remove the current one; it will just continue playing the
>   track you just removed! To solve this problem, you need to assign
>   another shortcut key to skip the removed track and start playing the
>   next one.
>
> Note also that if you highlight some file other than the currently
>   playing, Foobar will remove the highlighted track and not the one
>   currently playing.

Answer (score 0):

For all of those who have similar problem - 2 steps:

1. Enable `Cursor follows playback` option under `Playback` menu in the
   main window.
2. `File >> Preferences >> Keyboard Shortcuts`:

   - add new global shortcut for `Edit >> Selection >> Remove`,
   - add new global shortcut for `Playback >> Next`.

**Thanks to harrymc for providing the link.**